# sequence files from sqoop import

Tags: pyspark, sqoop, sequencefile

I have imported a table using sqoop and saved it as a sequence file.

How do I read this file into an RDD or Dataframe?

I have tried `sc.sequenceFile()` but I'm not sure what to pass as keyClass and value Class. I tried tried using org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable for keyClass and valueClass 
but it did not work. I am using pyspark for reading the files.

Comment: Minor edits to grammar and presentation and removed unnecessary text. Question could benefit from someone familiar with these tags in case additional clarity could be added by tag-knowledgeable volunteers. Question still requires attention from OP to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

in python its not working however in SCALA it works:

You need to do following steps:

step1:
If you are importing as sequence file from sqoop, there is a jar file generated, you need to use that as ValueClass while reading sequencefile. This jar file is generally placed in /tmp folder, but you can redirect it to a specific folder (i.e. to local folder not hdfs)  using --bindir option.

example: 
    sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ms.itversity.com/retail_export -- 
 username retail_user --password itversity --table customers -m 1 --target-dir '/user/srikarthik/udemy/practice4/problem2/outputseq' --as-sequencefile --delete-target-dir  --bindir /home/srikarthik/sqoopjars/

step2:
Also, you need to download the jar file from below link: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqoop144hadoop200jar.htm

step3:
Suppose, customers table is imported using sqoop as sequence file.
Run spark-shell --jars path-to-customers.jar,sqoop-1.4.4-hadoop200.jar

example:

```
spark-shell --master yarn --jars /home/srikarthik/sqoopjars/customers.jar,/home/srikarthik/tejdata/kjar/sqoop-1.4.4-hadoop200.jar
```

step4: Now run below commands inside the spark-shell

```
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

scala> val data = sc.sequenceFile[LongWritable,customers]("/user/srikarthik/udemy/practice4/problem2/outputseq")

scala> data.map(tup => (tup._1.get(), tup._2.toString())).collect.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SeqDataSourceV2](https://github.com/garawalid/seq-datasource-v2) package to read the sequence file with the DataFrame API without any prior knowledge of the schema (aka keyClass and valueClass).
Please note that the current version is only compatible with Spark 2.4

```sh
$ pyspark --packages seq-datasource-v2-0.2.0.jar
```

```py
df = spark.read.format("seq").load("data.seq")
df.show()
```